# ggplot - how to "highlight" one segment of a curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_function(fun = ~ 2*-.x^2 + 2*.x + 3)
```

[image]

Now I want to "highlight" one segment of the curve as on the following photo made in Paint:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `xlim` argument to a second `geom_function`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_function(fun = ~ 2*-.x^2 + 2*.x + 3) +
  geom_function(fun = ~ 2*-.x^2 + 2*.x + 3, xlim=c(.25, .5), color = 'blue', size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>